# Issue with Gsuite

Tags: authentication, google-workspace, spf, dkim

Can anyone help what causes Gsuite to do this?

[image: Google DSN showing message blocked]

It says: GSuite error 550 5.7.26 mail is unauthenticated. The sender must authenticate with at least one of SPF or DKIM.

Tried to click the google support link but nothing helped at all. Can someone elaborate what causes GSuite to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounce back message you're getting normally means that you do not have email authentication records properly configured in your domain. From the screenshot, your domain's SPF record does not allow emails sent from Google's IP address and since your email did not pass DKIM checks, you most likely do not have a DKIM record configured.

I suggest adding a DKIM record generated from Google Workspace's Admin Console and replacing your domain's SPF record with Google's. You can add both the DKIM and SPF records through your domain or hosting provider. You can get in touch with your domain or hosting provider for further assistance with adding the records

### References

- [Turning on DKIM authentication](https://support.google.com/a/answer/180504?hl=en)
- [Google's SPF record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10684623?hl=en&sjid=8104675958460548609-AP#:%7E:text=v%3Dspf1%20include%3A_spf.google.com%20%7Eall)

Comment: Hi Darym, was the answer below able to fix your issue? 

Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you

Comment: This issue has been resolved by the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)